# Making my own Signal Source Block using Python Module in GNURadio

Tags: python, gnuradio-companion

I  have made my own Signal Source using Python Module Block, I have a problem getting the output of self-coded Signal Source Block at different frequencies (in fact i don't know how to do it). The only output that shows in FFT plot is at 0(MHz). Whereas i want the output in FFT plot to be at various frequencies(1MHz, 2MHz...), the same way as a built-in Signal Source Block does.

The working code is:

```
for i in range(0,len(output_items[0])-1):
 output_items[0][i]= math.sin(2*3.14*(i)/self.fs_local)
 return len(output_items[0])
```

I need to get idea of how to change it to get output at various frequencies, This code shows output at 0MHz only.

Comment: um, what is the role of `self.fs_local`? Also, nope, you'll get phase discontinuities at the edges of `work` calls this way. Can't do it like that!

Comment: Just a variable declared so i can see it in properties of the python module block. Actually i tried to vary it using a slider to see the effect on its fft plot.
And you mean the plot cannot be displayed the way i want it to (at 1MHz, 2Mhz...) ?

Comment: have you made a function that actually changes that variable when you use the slider? Debug!

Comment: It does change with almost no effect on fft plot.
i think it has nothing to do with fft plot to get changed.
The variable can be declared as constant of value 4096 which i have been doing.

Comment: I mean, have you *checked* that the value gets actually changed? Because clearly, your FFT plot says it doesn't.

Comment: It changes the output_item value but not in a manner to drag it to any other frequency no matter how high or low the value of fs_local is!

Comment: then it doesn't work, so you need to debug the way you set `fs_local` and how you apply it (hint: you do that incorrectly!)

Comment: So, should i change the range or value of it or go for any other?

Comment: you need to debug and understand what you're doing. the way you applied `fs_local` is not right. I think this should get you started.

Comment: Fine, i'll think over it, Thanks!